# how to set camera's look-at point when moves along a curve?

Tags: python, bezier-curves, camera

I want to have my camera moves by "Follow Path", it moves pretty well except that its view angle is not what I want.

I want to have the camera's look-at point always to be the next point it moves to. How can I get this work with python script? (or is there a setting for that)

My guess is that if I set the rotation angle correctly at the beginning it will fulfill my requirement.

```
pi = 3.1415926
scene.camera.rotation_mode = 'XYZ'
scene.camera.rotation_euler[0] = rx*(pi/180.0)
scene.camera.rotation_euler[1] = ry*(pi/180.0)
scene.camera.rotation_euler[2] = rz*(pi/180.0)
```

where rx,ry,rz are the euler angle that I need to calculate at the beginning.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you are using the Follow Path constraint check "follow curve" option and set "forward" to Z and "UP" to Y

Comment: are you doing the "follow path" using a script not a constraint ?

Comment: @Chebhou yes. I used "follow path" in the script. How can I set constraint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can access and alter the properties of the constraints of an object, all constraints are listed in `object.constraints`, access each constraint by its name or type and of course the index

```
cam = scene.camera
# if you are sure the constraint exist and has the default name
fol_path = cam.constraints['Follow Path']

fol_path.forward_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
fol_path.up_axis = 'UP_Y'

# to avoid errors in case it doesn't exist or has another name
for cons in cam.constraints :
    if cons.type == 'FOLLOW_PATH':
        cons.forward_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
        cons.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
```

Comment: there is error with fol_path = cam.constraints['Follow Path'] : KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Follow Path" not found'

Comment: because the camera doesn't have the follow path constraint you have to add a follow path constraint to the camera before trying to access it , also to avoid errors you can use the second part , if you still have problems comment back